# Can I autoregister my clients/servers in local DNS?

Tags: dns, dynamic-dns, nameserver

Right now I have a W2k12 server at home that I run as a domain controller. This has the extra benefit of registering every "subordinate" computers name in it's DNS so that I don't have to go around remembering IP's all the time. (And it let's me easily run dhcp also on my servers).

I need to rework my home network for several odd reasons, and in this new scenario there is no place for a big honking W2k12 server box. I have a RasPI, and I have other smallish linux boxen I can use. (In a worst case scenario I'll use my NUC, but then I'll be forced to use my home cinema's UPnP-client for media... The HORROR!!)

Is it possible to set up a DNS-server-"appliance" that somehow autoregisters it's own hostname..

## Scenario:

- Router (N66u) on 172.20.20.1. Runs DHCP on 172.20.20.100-200 range.
- Server [verdant] of a *nix flavor on 172.20.20.2
- Laptop [speedy] of W8 flavor on DHCP assigned
- Laptop [canary] of W8 flavor on DHCP assigned
- Desktop [lianyu] of Ubunto flavor on DHCP assigned

What I would like is that all of the above servers (except possibly the router) would be available on `verdant.starling.lan` and `canary.starling.lan` and so on. This is how it works right now (except the Ubuntu box... I haven't cracked that one yet) because Windows just does this for you.. I would also be able to do this without any manual labor on the server. When I tell my box it's name is `smoak` it should "immediately" be available as `smoak.starling.lan` without any extra configuration on my part.

How can I do this in a Linux (Ubuntu) environment?

(Bonus comment upvote for naming the naming scheme :P )

Comment: All I can suggest is keeping your Win2012 server, maybe just virtualize it so it's not taking up physical real-estate.  Otherwise you have a lot of research and trial-and-error ahead of you to replicate what Microsoft was doing for you.  What you are describing is a typical small business environment.

Comment: They didn't seem to think so over at ServerFault ;)